# navbar-collapse conflict with position elements

Tags: jquery, mobile, toggle, navbar

I'm having a problem with my website, it's a store locator page. But when you resize your window if you're in PC as if you're in mobile resolution, when you toggle the navbar-collapse, the navbar will be underneath the sidebar which looks very ugly. Is there something wrong with my CSS?

**[DEMO](http://www.jinzai-beta2v.esy.es/main/stores)**

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vFV2p.png)

```
body {
      color:#404040;
      font:400 15px/22px 'Source Sans Pro', 'Helvetica Neue', Sans-serif;
      margin:0;
      padding:0;
      -webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased;
    }

    * {
      -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
      -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
      box-sizing:border-box;
    }
    .sidebar {
      position:absolute;
      width:33.3333%;
      height:100%;
      top:90px;left:0;
      overflow:hidden;
      border-right:1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
    }

    .map {
      position:absolute;
      left:33.3333%;
      width:66.6666%;
      top:90px;bottom:0;
    }
```

**Update (08/10/2017):** *The problem was solved by the ff:*

> Okay, wrap the sidebar and map in a new div with position:relative and
>   height:100vh; – thehuijb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add

```
.dark-header .menu-header, .header-dark .menu-header {
    position:relative;
}
```

Comment: Thank you sir! you're a life saver! however, it overlaps the screen, which is not bad at all. But it would be better if the collapse will not overlap the screen instead, it will push the sidebar and the map downwards.

Comment: Okay, wrap the siebar and map in a new div with position:relative and height:100vh;

Comment: and set top:0; on the sidebar and map

Comment: Dude I did everything you said and it magically solves my entire problem. I don't know what does the "height: 100vh" does but doesn't matter, you're one of the wizards here in stackoverflow. Thank you very very VERY much! Problem solved after 5 days!

Comment: Please add a little bit of explanation as to why and how the code above solves the issue at hand

Comment: it comes down to positioning elements  absolute positioning is positioning absolutely within its container, without a wrapper they would be positioned absolute on the body element.

Comment: the other thing is, absolute positioned elements do not give their container any height, that's why you have to give it a height, 100vh is 100percent of the viewport height.